# Unable to create/find tab for Survey Invitation object

Tags: permissions, profile, salesforce-survey, tab-settings, custom-tab

I have enabled Surveys in Salesforce and the Survey tab is visible to the user. However, I am unable to find the tab for Survey Invitation.

For profiles, the tab setting is unavailable:
[image]

I cannot find the option to create a custom tab as well:
[image]

However, I can see a standard tab under Rename Tabs option:
[image]

Is there any specific setting I am missing to enable this tab? I could not find any Salesforce Help document that state that this tab isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Survey Invitation List View / Tab is not exposed by default since they don't actually make a lot of sense without a context Survey.

As a workaround to load the Invitation list, you can just modify the URL and append the following after the domain name: `lightning/o/SurveyInvitation/list?filterName=Recent`

For example: https://xxxxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/SurveyInvitation/list?filterName=Recent

Comment: Yes, I figured out the part for the list view but I had hoped Salesforce would provide some sort of documentation for this behaviour. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I couldn't find any Salesforce documentation on this. Ideally, what is not documented is not supported. But I'll update this thread if I find any relevant article. Thanks